# Return Json with Nodejs, datas of SQL SERVER ( (express y tedious)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sql-server, express

I am trying to transform the data that I obtain with my query to the SQL database in a json to be sent through a query in my REST API.

```
const express = require('express');
const Request = require('tedious').Request;

const app = express(); // creo mi app

const db = require('./db'); // conexion a la db

app.get('/series', (req, res) => {


    const request = new Request(`SELECT VALOR1,VALOR2 FROM DATABASE`, (err, rowCount, rows) => {

        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        } else {
            console.log(`${rowCount} row(s) returned`); // APARECE VALOR 63
        };

        jsonArray = [];

        rows.forEach(function(columns) {

            var rowObject = {};

            columns.forEach(function(column) {
                rowObject[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
            });

            jsonArray.push(rowObject);
        });

        res.json(jsonArray);
    });

    db.execSql(request);

});
```

But the result is [] (without any value inside), when I make the Get request (with potman and in the browser). I have tried to send with the res.send () function and the result is the same.

Where can the error be?

Thanks in advance :)

PD: code from my file db.js

```
const {Connection} = require("tedious");

// Create connection to database
const config = {
  authentication: {
    options: {
      userName: "users", // update me
      password: "users" // update me
    },
    type: "default"
  },
  server: "srvdesarrollo", // update me
  options: {
    database: "users", //update me
    encrypt: false
  }
};

const connection = new Connection(config);

module.exports = connection;
```

Comment: I think you can easily debug this by adding `console.log` inside your `forEach` loop, and also just before sending the response back. So you see what you get from the DB, and also what happens inside `forEach` and hopefully, figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I can easily debug this by adding console.log, but that doesn't fix the error. The JSON is being formed properly but when it is returned it appears empty ([])

Comment: So if it's being formed properly, the problem isn't in the code you gave, it's in the front-end.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved it !! what I did was put the res.json (jsonArray); in the first else where it shows the total of rows